# Building an HLSL shader with FXC.exe, what's the simplest way to get the byte code itself in a binary file?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, binaryfiles, hlsl

For example, let's say I have "HLSLStructureTest.hlsl", and I want to have a binary file "HLSLStructureTestBytecode.bin" which contains the byte code for my compiled shader.  Is there maybe an option I can include when running FXC.exe to get that?  Or some other thing I'd need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `/Fo <file>` switch, which outputs to an "object file" that contains the shader bytecode.